# NPE while adding data to AChartEngine Line Chart

Tags: android, charts, achartengine

I am getting this NullPointerException when my data is being added to the chart. Here is my some of my data (nothing is null):

```
11-21 21:09:36.286: I/System.out(10682): 51.0 | -13.3 | 77.0
11-21 21:09:36.286: I/System.out(10682): 55.0 | -13.0 | 78.0
11-21 21:09:36.294: I/System.out(10682): 52.0 | -12.8 | 79.0
11-21 21:09:36.294: I/System.out(10682): 57.0 | -12.8 | 79.0
11-21 21:09:36.294: I/System.out(10682): 57.0 | -12.7 | 80.0
11-21 21:09:36.294: I/System.out(10682): 58.0 | -11.6 | 80.0
11-21 21:09:36.294: I/System.out(10682): 57.0 | -10.6 | 80.0
11-21 21:09:36.294: I/System.out(10682): 58.0 | -9.1 | 81.0
11-21 21:09:36.301: I/System.out(10682): 59.0 | -8.9 | 82.0
11-21 21:09:36.301: I/System.out(10682): 59.0 | -8.6 | 82.0
11-21 21:09:36.301: I/System.out(10682): 59.0 | -8.8 | 82.0
11-21 21:09:36.301: I/System.out(10682): 59.0 | -9.0 | 83.0
11-21 21:09:36.301: I/System.out(10682): 58.0 | -9.5 | 83.0
11-21 21:09:36.301: I/System.out(10682): 57.0 | -9.6 | 83.0
11-21 21:09:36.301: I/System.out(10682): 58.0 | -9.3 | 83.0
```

The error log says:

```
11-21 21:09:36.426: E/AndroidRuntime(10682): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-21 21:09:36.426: E/AndroidRuntime(10682): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-21 21:09:36.426: E/AndroidRuntime(10682):    at android.view.ViewConfiguration.get(ViewConfiguration.java:323)
11-21 21:09:36.426: E/AndroidRuntime(10682):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3271)
11-21 21:09:36.426: E/AndroidRuntime(10682):    at org.achartengine.GraphicalView.<init>(GraphicalView.java:91)
11-21 21:09:36.426: E/AndroidRuntime(10682):    at org.achartengine.ChartFactory.getLineChartView(ChartFactory.java:70)
11-21 21:09:36.426: E/AndroidRuntime(10682):    at com.jasonflaherty.snoteldata.BCMarkerInformation$CheckTask.onPostExecute(BCMarkerInformation.java:321)
11-21 21:09:36.426: E/AndroidRuntime(10682):    at com.jasonflaherty.snoteldata.BCMarkerInformation$CheckTask.onPostExecute(BCMarkerInformation.java:1)
11-21 21:09:36.426: E/AndroidRuntime(10682):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
11-21 21:09:36.426: E/AndroidRuntime(10682):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
11-21 21:09:36.426: E/AndroidRuntime(10682):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
11-21 21:09:36.426: E/AndroidRuntime(10682):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-21 21:09:36.426: E/AndroidRuntime(10682):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-21 21:09:36.426: E/AndroidRuntime(10682):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
11-21 21:09:36.426: E/AndroidRuntime(10682):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-21 21:09:36.426: E/AndroidRuntime(10682):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-21 21:09:36.426: E/AndroidRuntime(10682):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
11-21 21:09:36.426: E/AndroidRuntime(10682):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
11-21 21:09:36.426: E/AndroidRuntime(10682):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Line 321 has my chart setup:

```
mChart = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(ctx, mDataset, mRenderer);
```

I have added other data to a chart setup exactly like this, so I am not sure where this NPE is coming from. Just an FYI, according to my logcat, it doesn't reach this far down the code, but I have a table layout setup like so:

```
<TableRow
            android:id="@+id/GraphRow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#59473d"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/chart"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_span="4"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:orientation="horizontal" />
        </TableRow>
```

I have tried adding the graph to just a simple xml layout with just the linearlayout... so I am fairly sure that is not the problem.

I setup the layout: `LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart);`

I add it to the layout: `layout.addView(mChart);`

Any ideas on where to start here? I'm at a loss currently. Anything else I can add to the question?

Comment: I used getBaseContext(); instead of ctx and was able to get it to show data here: mChart = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(ctx, mDataset, mRenderer);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the `context` value you pass to the method in `ChartFactory` is `null`.

Comment: Yes. Thanks @Dan. I was pulling my hair until I submitted the darn question, then had that though. Sheeesh.